# Zip method in RXJava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I am learning RX Java where I would like to send N parallel requests to a web API and the combined results would be merged to one List. I am using Retrofit with RXJava extensions to send the requests:

```
@GET("getForkliftDetail")
Observable<ForkliftDetail> getForkliftDetail(
        @Query("lang") String language,
        @Query("id") Integer forkliftId);
```

My function which sends the requests looks like this:

```
List<Observable<ForkliftDetail>> requests = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Forklift item: forkliftParkList) {
        requests.add(service.fetchForkliftDetails(locale, item.getId()));
    }
    Observable.zip(
            requests,
            new FuncN(){
                public ForkliftDetail call(ForkliftDetail... args) {
                    Log.i("RX TEST", args.toString());
                    return new ForkliftDetail();
                }})
            // After all requests had been performed the next observer will receive the Object, returned from Function
            .subscribe(
                    // Will be triggered if all requests will end successfully (4xx and 5xx also are successful requests too)
                    new Consumer<Object>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(Object o) throws Exception {
                            //Do something on successful completion of all requests
                        }
                    },

                    // Will be triggered if any error during requests will happen
                    new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(Throwable e) throws Exception {
                            //Do something on error completion of requests
                        }
                    }
            );
```

However, I am stuck at this point. The `FuncN` error says i need to implement `call(Object...)`. I thought `FuncN` method is where I can add all responses, `ForkliftDetail` objects, to a new List and return it. Please help me to understand this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a generics issue, maybe you need to specify `new FuncN<>()`?

Comment: same error message with `new FuncN<ForkliftDetail, List<ForkliftDetail>>(){
                    public List<ForkliftDetail> call(ForkliftDetail detail) {
                        Log.i("RX TEST", detail.toString());
                        return new ArrayList<ForkliftDetail>();
                    }})`

Comment: FuncN takes `Object[]` and returns `R`. You have to specify `call(Object[] values)`, then manually cast each `values` item to `ForkliftDetail`.

Comment: Also there is a mixup here; are you using RxJava 1 or 2? `FuncN` is for RxJava 1 and `Consumer` is in RxJava 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
List<Observable<ForkliftDetail>> requests = new ArrayList<>();
for (Forklift item: forkliftParkList) {
    requests.add(service.fetchForkliftDetails(locale, item.getId()));
}

Observable.zip(
    requests,
    new Function<Object[], ForkliftDetail>() {
        @Override
        public ForkliftDetail apply(Object[] args) {
                Log.i("RX TEST", Arrays.toString(args));
                return new ForkliftDetail();
            }
        }
    )
    .subscribe(
        new Consumer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Object o) throws Exception {
            }
        },
        new Consumer<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Throwable e) throws Exception {
            }
        }
    );
```